# Rewrite URL with query parameters in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, query-string

Say I have these urls:

```
https://example.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=cad
https://example.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=videos
https://example.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=news
```

How can I rewrite these in `.htaccess` to something like this:

```
https://example.com/cad
https://example.com/videos
https://example.com/news
```

This is my attempt thus far. I know that my rewrite method is solid because it works on URL's without query strings. I tried the QSA flag (Query String Append) to no avail.

```
Options -MultiViews 

RewriteRule ^bbs/board.php?bo_table=cad$ /caster-cad-downloads [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^caster-cad-downloads$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=cad [END]

RewriteRule ^bbs/board.php?bo_table=video$ /caster-videos [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^caster-videos$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=video [END]

RewriteRule ^bbs/board.php?bo_table=news$ /news [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=news [END]
```

How can I rewrite to a different URL instead of the query string while still using the
`%{QUERY_STRING` method?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bo_table=(cad|videos|news)$
RewriteRule ^bbs/board\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
# RewriteRule ^(caster-cad-downloads|caster-videos|news)$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^(?:caster-(cad)-downloads|caster-(videos)|(news))$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1 [END]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I rewrite these in `.htaccess` to something like this:

The "rewrite" is the other way round (as mentioned previously). The incoming request is for `/cad` and this is internally rewritten to `/bbs/board.php?bo_table=cad` that actually handles the request.

This can be achieved with a single rule since these 3 URLs follow the same pattern (although that conflicts with the code sample you've posted). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(cad|videos|news)$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1 [END]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the value of the first capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. either `cad`, `videos` or `news`.

The external redirect is not strictly necessary, unless you are *changing* an existing URL structure. Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. (So your rules that include a query string would never match.) To match the query string you need an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. For example, the following would go **before** the above rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bo_table=(cad|videos|news)$
RewriteRule ^bbs/board\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Note that we need to use the `QSD` flag here in order to *discard* the original query string, we don't want to append it.

The `%1` backreference (as opposed to `$1`) matches the capturing group in the last matched *CondPattern* (`RewriteCond` directive).

Don't forget to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex in order to negate their special meaning.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(cad-downloads|cad-videos|news)$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1 [END]
> ```

To pass `cad`, `videos` (`video`?) or `news` as the URL parameter, you could do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:(cad)-downloads|cad-(videos)|(news))$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1 [END]
```

This is made possible because `cad`, `videos` and `news` are still part of the requested URL. The outer regex group is made non-capturing (with the `?:` prefix). An additional capturing group inside this captures the necessary *part* of the requested URL.

However, the reverse is not possible without hardcoding the mappings.

<sub>I'll see if I can get back to your other queries/chat tomorrow...</sub>

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks, once again. Please see the code I added to the question. This is what I tried in `.htaccess` and it's not seeming to work.

Comment: @user Sorry, typo... should be `cad`, not `car` (I've updated my answer). And the rules should be the other way round (not that it matters too much in this instance). However, you should be requesting `/cad`, not `/bbs/board.php?bo_table=cad`.

Comment: got to love typos. It's working now! Can you edit my code in my question to show me what you mean in the last part? I think it may matter. I keep getting an alert now on those URLS. I actually changed what I want the rewritten URLS to be, see question. Will that not work since it's not part of the initial query string?

Comment: It's still redirecting to /cad ... I should have stated this initially, but what if we wanted to make the new url different from the initial query param. This example is extremely helpful though in other scenarios.

Comment: is this not possible?

Comment: @user "what if we wanted to make the new url different from the initial query param" - That's tricky. In this example, you could perhaps still construct the rewrite in a single rule since the value you pass in the query param is a subset of what is in the URL, but the redirect is not so easy. You can use a "rewrite map" (if you have access to the server config), or create a separate rule for each. (But, as stated, the redirect is not essential for this to function. You should not be relying on the redirect for this to work.)

Comment: Interesting, so would I need a rewrite map for that to work, or could I still get it to work just in .hta? I am still changing the `href`'s themselves as we discussed. The only reason I want the redirect is if that link is from a third-party source. The ones from the menu most likely are, but some of the other ones I have to do are not so I can just do a rewrite and no redirect. Can you edit my code in the question to show me an example of that would look like in .hta to make at least these query params redirect to different URLs? I have 600+ more that won't need the redirect.

Comment: @user I've updated my answer with an example of the "rewrite".

Comment: Once again appreciated, htaccess

Comment: One last thought, what if I wanted to put something before the `(cad)` in `(cad)-downloads`?

Comment: @user That's OK. (Try it ;)

Comment: Not working... I have `RewriteRule ^(?:caster-(cad)-downloads|caster-(videos)|(news))$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1 [END]`

Comment: @user Hhhmm, it should work, if the previous worked. It should rewrite `/caster-cad-downloads` to `bbs/board.php?bo_table=cad`. (Make sure the cache is cleared.)

Comment: It's redirecting `/cad` to `bbs/board.php?bo_table=cad` and `/videos` to `bbs/board.php?bo_table=videos`. News appears to be working, but it keeps giving me a JS alert so I don't know if it's from improper redirect or not fetching the data. Please check the question for the updated code on my side.

Comment: Any update? We can continue this in the chat again if you'd like.