RewriteRule /category?id=2 to /index.php?cat=2
I want /category?id=2 to redirect to /index?cat=2 in .htaccess
I have tried with the following code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^category?id=$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]

But nothing happens. I understand that there is something wrong with my code. Anyone know what I should change?

RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only. To match on query string contents, you need to use a RewriteCond that accesses the corresponding variable, see f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75478853/1427878

The documentation of the rewriting module clearly states that a RewriteRule is matched against the path component of the requested URL. Not against the query string. To match that you can add a RewriteCondition, you can also capture strings from there and reference them using a "%" notation:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^/?category$ /index.php?cat=%1 [QSD,L]

There might be additional steps you have to take to make this work. Obviously the rewriting module has to be loaded and activated inside your http server. And the application of such rewriting rules from within a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") has to be enabled first (see the documentation for the AllowOverride directive). The file needs to be readable for the http server process. And it has to be located inside the http host's DocumentRoot folder.
